# Does the iPhone have a built-in caching mechanism (per application)?

Tags: iphone, caching, xamarin.ios

Do I have to roll my own caching mechanism for data I'd like to persist, or is there something built-in that I can leverage? Any help would be great - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in caching mechanism per-se, but SQLite, CoreData, etc. are available (or you could just use the built in NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver if you're only interested in storing a small amount of data (such as user preferences) in standard language objects and don't want to use a plist based settings approach.

That said, I'm not sure how/if these are wrapped in monotouch. (Search for the above NSKeyed.. methods and NSCoding and all should be revealed.)

Answer (score 1):

What variety of persist are you interested in?

For long term storage there is CoreData and sqlite.
For inter invocation storage there are UserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a little data--especially if it's user preferences and settings--there is NSUserDefaults. That's a pretty handy auto-persisting data interface. But it's not built for mass amounts of data.